# what happens if puts() function doesn't encounter null character?

Tags: c, null, puts

Consider following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char side_a[] = "Side A";
    char dont[] = {'W', 'O', 'W', '!' }; 
    char side_b[] = "Side B";
    puts(dont); /* dont is not a string */
    return 0;
}
```

I know that puts() function stops when it encounters the null character. But in above program I haven't specified null character. So when it stops printing? Is this program invokes undefined behavior? Is it guaranteed to get same output for this program on various C compilers? What the C standard says about this?

Comment: In C a valid string is the one which is null terminated , all lib API's expect the null terminated string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`puts` will end up reading past the last element of `dont`, which is undefined behavior.

So no, you are not guaranteed the same output every time. You're not guaranteed any output at all for that matter - you're not guaranteed *anything* since this is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this error results in your program having no defined behavior. As the term indicates, you can't expect anything reasonable to come out of the execution of such a program.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it will be [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so output won't be same all the time.
If you want to print in such case, I would suggest as below to have uniform output:

```
printf("%.*s", 4, dont);
```

Comment: Good suggestion.  One would be tempted to use `sizeof(dont)` to handle changes in its definition gracefully, but be careful to cast it as `(int)` to avoid undefined behaviour: `printf("%.*s", (int)sizeof(dont), dont);`.  This solution isn't perfect anyway since it would silently misbehave if `dont` is changed to a `char *`.